# In an inner product space that is not complete, is there a closed orthonormal system that is also complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be an inner product space and $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an orthonormal system. We call it complete if $\left \langle v,e_n \right \rangle=0$ for all $n$ implies $v=0$; and closed if $v=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left \langle v,e_n \right \rangle e_n$ for every $v\in V$.

My question is this: is there a closed orthonormal system that is also complete in an inner product space that is not complete (not a hilbert space)?

Comment: Every "closed" orthonormal system is automatically complete. In the space $c_{00}$ of complex sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms, viewed as a subspace of $\ell^2$, the "standard basis" is a closed orthonormal set (it's a Hilbert basis of $\ell^2$). So it certainly is possible that an incomplete inner product space contains closed (and hence complete) orthonormal sets. But I don't know whether every (separable) incomplete inner product space contains one.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think the situation you describe is the generic one. The closure of a separable inner product space will be a separable Hilbert space and thus isomorphic to $\ell^2$). Also Gram-Schmidt should provide us with a "closed" orthonormal family.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I lean towards expecting that there's always some Hilbert basis of the completion that's contained in $V$, at least in the separable case. But things aren't entirely straightforward. Consider $\xi \in \ell^2 \setminus c_{00}$, and a maximal orthonormal system in $c_{00} \cap \langle \xi\rangle^{\perp}$. Then this is a maximal (hence complete) orthonormal system in $c_{00}$ too, but not closed. Thus in an incomplete inner product space there can be complete ON systems that aren't closed. It's not obvious (to me) that we can always avoid situations like that one.

Comment: could you consider accepting the answer, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the trigonometric Fourier series in $C^0([0,2\pi])$ the space of all continuous functions with the $L^2$-norm.
$$
||f||_2:=\left(\int_0^{2\pi} |f(x)|^2\,{\rm d}x\right)^{1/2}
$$

This is **not complete inner product space** in the Cauchy sense, but it is known that any vector (continuous function) in $C^0([0,2\pi])$ has a Fourier expansion (**closed**). And the zero vector is the only one with zero coefficeints (**complete**).

**Note** the closedness and completeness of the the orthonormal systems have nothing to do with topology. Actaully, the set of all (finite) linear combinations of trigonometric function $\cos nx$, $\sin nx$ and some constant is neither complete (Cauchy sense) nor closed (not every limit point is in it). See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808778/closed-or-not-but-incomplete-subspace-of-an-incomplete-inner-product-space).